# to display student details from and list of array,by validating or using a 6 digit string of code in php?

Tags: php

`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>string checker</title>
</head>
<body>
 <?php

 $student_1 =array("name"=>"deepak","bc"=>"bca","year"=>2,"e_roll"=>001);
 $student_2 = array("name"=>"aditya","bs"=>"bs-it","year"=>2,"e_roll"=>002);
 $student_3 = array("name"=>"kissan","mc"=>"mca","year"=>3,"e_roll"=>003);
 $student_4 = array("name"=>"Shubham","bc"=>"bca","year"=>1,"e_roll"=>004);
 $student_5 = array("name"=>"vivek","bc"=>"bca","year"=>3,"e_roll"=>005);
 $student_6 = array("name"=>"rohit","mc"=>"mca","year"=>2,"e_roll"=>0003);

 $test_1="bc1001";
 $test_2="mc2003";
 $test_3="bs2002";

 $test_1 = str_replace(array_keys($student_1),$student_1,$test_1);









 ?>

</body>
</html>
```

**using test_1 i want to  display student_1 details**

`we have a **6 character alpha-numerical string**.
1st two-character represents a program or course he/she pursuing**(eg; bs-BSC(it),bc-BCA,mc-MCA)**.
next char represents in which year he/she studying.
and remaining char represents roll no.

sample of the string is **bc1001** should display student name course as BCA, year first and roll no 001

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: Hi, what is your expected outcome/question? HTML-Code, Array, JSON, ..?

Comment: `$prog = $string[0] . $string[1]; $year = $string[2]; $roll = substr($string, 3)` would do it, or a regex.. multiple ways. Please show what you tried.

Comment: from list of an array which contains details of students like course, year, enrollment no. we have given a unique code of 6 characters containing alphanumerical.  example bc1001 should display BCA as course a year as one and enrollment no as 001 with students name

Answer (score 0):

You can use substr() to get the portions of the string that you want to compare, then do what you want with them from there. The manual can provide more specific usage of substr: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Ex:

```
$course = substr('bc1001', 0, 2); // will output "bc"
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear what your expectation is but in general you could achieve this in multiple ways. One of it is regular expressions with `preg_match` https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.preg-match.php

Here is an example:

```
$string = 'bc1001';

preg_match('#([\w]{2})(\d{1})(\d{3})#i', $string, $matches);
```

Result:

```
var_dump($matches[1], $matches[2], $matches[3]);

// string(2) "bc"
// string(1) "1"
// string(3) "001"
```